# How to insert one of the camera image into the html element--input?

Tags: html, css, image

Here is the special camera,two cameras in one image.
[image]

The target web page.

[image]

To insert a camera image in the input element.
Restrictive condition:
the two-cameras image cann't be slice into new image containing only one camera.

Here is my html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
input{
    width:538px;
    height:50px;
    background:url(camera.png) no-repeat  scroll 510px 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" maxlength="100" >
</body>
</html>
```

I can't display only one camera ,how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one way.

HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;">
  <input type="text" maxlength="100" >
  <div class="camera-bg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input{
    width:538px;
    height:50px;
   padding-right:40px;
    }
.camera-bg{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:0;
  width:30px;
  height:20px;
   background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vv2z.png) no-repeat ;
  background-position:0 0;
}
```

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/swapnaranjitanayak/pen/PbjLqX[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/swapnaranjitanayak/pen/PbjLqX)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your input with a `div` and add this CSS code:

```css
.camera {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.camera:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vv2z.png)
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input {
      width: 238px;
      height: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="camera">
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a write a more in html. In your case it is a background-position not a background-color

```css
.form-input {
  position:relative;
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
   .icon {
     content:"";
     width: 30px;
     height:30px;
     display:block;
     background:  url(camera.png) no-repeat center center;
     background-color:red;
     position:absolute;
     right:10px;
     top:50%;
     margin-top:-15px;
     z-index:2;
   }

input{
    width:538px;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:1em;
    }
    
    input:focus ~ .icon {
       background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-input">
  <input type="text" maxlength="100" >
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```